# What are the differences between these IBM.Data.DB2 dlls?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, db2, db2-connect

I have these dlls installed on my box. What are the differnces between them and when would I use each?

```
IBM.Data.DB2.dll
IBM.Data.DB2.Entity.dll
IBM.Data.DB2.ASP.dll
IBM.Data.DB2.9.5.5.dll
```

One other thing, my db2 data is on Z/OS Mainframe, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "my box" I assume you mean something like a Windows desktop client that you use to connect to your [DB2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_DB2) data source. The article *[Which DB2 9.5 client connectivity option is right for you?](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0804zikopoulos/)* explains (kind of) why you have all those different DLLs installed on your box.

The `IBM.Data.DB2.dll` file is the main resource reference you would add in Visual Studio to use its various methods. You can add all of those DLLs as references in a dummy Visual Studio project then browse them in the Object Browser, and you will see their different methods or lack of.